# Keep shopping cart total on page changes with jQuery session

Tags: jquery, session

I am looking at making a shopping cart on my site but I need to retain the visitors total and items selected when they browse through the site on different pages. So I have two questions if some one can kindly help.

First what is the best way to keep this data, at the moment I am trying to use jQuery session but is this the best solution.

Using session I have the following problem which I believe is where the cart total is being converted to a string.

I have the following test script

```
var panel4Price = 15;       
var cartTotal = sessionStorage.getItem("cartTotal");

$('#addCart').click(function(){
    cartTotal = cartTotal + panel4Price;
    $('#cart').html('£ ' + cartTotal);
    sessionStorage.setItem("cartTotal", cartTotal);

    console.log(cartTotal);
});
```

When I run this with out the session being added to the cartTotal variable the cartTotal adds up correctly, but as soon as I try to call the session cartTotal at the beginning it adds the price as a string like this 15151515. Hope this makes sense.

Edit - So I have worked out that I can pass back the session as an integer using the following.

```
var cartTotal = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("cartTotal"));
```

This works ok as long as there is a total in the cart in the first place but if the cart is empty I get Nan so how can I set the cart at 0 if the cart is empty.

Comment: You can "or" that with zero: `var cartTotal = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("cartTotal")) || 0`

Comment: great such an easy fix. thank you